# Cannot submit form with CasperJS - in other words cannot login

Tags: javascript, node.js, tumblr, casperjs

I'm trying to login into Tumblr with CasperJS using methods `start`, `fill` and `waitForUrl` but **cannot** do this. **It seems to me that form wasn't submitted**, because timeout in `waitForUr` expired everytime.

*Terminal response:*
[image]

*Code I'm using is this:*

```
/*jslint browser: true, regexp: true */
// global casper, require 

var LOGIN_URL, LOGIN_USERNAME, LOGIN_PASSWORD, casper;

casper = require('casper').create({
    waitTimeout: 20000,
    viewportSize: {
        width: 1024,
        height: 768
    },
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: 'debug',
    userAgent: 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)'
});

if (!casper.cli.has('username') && !casper.cli.has('password')) {
    casper.echo('Usage: $ casperjs sfdclogin.casper.js --username=USERNAME --password=PASSWORD').exit(-1);
}

LOGIN_URL = 'https://tumblr.com/login';

LOGIN_USERNAME = casper.cli.get('username');
LOGIN_PASSWORD = casper.cli.get('password');

phantom.cookiesEnabled = true;

casper
    .start(LOGIN_URL, function () {
        // 'use strict';

        this.log('Logging in', 'debug');
        /*
        this.fillSelectors('#signup_form_form', {
            '#signup_email': LOGIN_USERNAME,
            '#signup_password': LOGIN_PASSWORD
        }, true);
        */

        this.fill('#signup_form_form', {
            '#user[email]': LOGIN_USERNAME,
            '#user[password]': LOGIN_PASSWORD
        }, true);
    })

    .waitForUrl('http://tumblr.com/dashboard', function () {
        // 'use strict';

        this.echo('We\'re logged in.');
    })

    .run();
```

*Also*, I'm using correct username and password with this script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using the following instead of your current `casper.fill()`.
This is because CasperJS' `fill()` searches for the name attribute of elements.

```js
this.fill('#signup_form', {
    'user[email]': LOGIN_USERNAME,
    'user[password]': LOGIN_PASSWORD
}, true);
```

You could use this if you want to continue using the ids as selectors.

```js
this.fillSelectors('#signup_form', {
    '#signup_email': LOGIN_USERNAME,
    '#signup_password': LOGIN_PASSWORD
}, true);
```

Comment: In your updated code, you still have the `#` before the selectors. It should look like `user[email]`. Also, you will need to change `#signup_form_form` to `#signup_form`

Comment: Thank you, the main problem was `#signup_form`