# Cannot load url and then, cannot send login parameters

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

I'm trying to login automatically in tumblr, running the script proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609394/cannot-submit-form-with-casperjs-in-other-words-cannot-login) but phantomjs only shows failed attempts:

```
[info] [phantom] Starting...
[info] [phantom] Running suite: 3 steps
[debug] [phantom] opening url: https://tumblr.com/login, HTTP GET
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://tumblr.com/login, type=Other,willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
[warning] [phantom] Loading resource failed with status=fail: https://tumblr.com/login
[debug] [phantom] Successfully injected Casper client-side utilities
[debug] [phantom] Logging in
[info] [remote] attempting to fetch form element from selector: '#signup_form'
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 2/3: done in 2899ms.
[info] [phantom] Step _step 3/3: done in 2912ms.
[warning] [phantom] Casper.waitFor() timeout  
[error] [phantom] Wait timeout of 100000ms expired, exiting.
Wait timeout of 100000ms expired, exiting.
```

I increased the original timeout script without success, my workstation uses:
 - Windows 7 64bits
 - Casperjs 1.1.0
 - Phantomjs 1.9.1

thanks.

Comment: Not sure what is going wrong here. I'm not able to access any page on their site, but it was working a week ago.

Comment: thanks for your comment, I don't have many experience but all others urls works well so I'll keep trying looking for any clue.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I finally found a solution for this issue.
Tumblr is using the TLSv1.2 encryption for their site while PhantomJS defaults to SSLv3.

To fix this, you can either call CasperJS with either:

```
casperjs tumblr.js --ssl-protocol=tlsv1
```

or

```
casperjs tumblr.js --ssl-protocol=any
```

Comment: Hi, I still have the "fail" message, I'm trying with casper 1.1.0 dev version, which version you tried? many thanks!

Comment: I'm CasperJS 1.1.0-dev and PhantomJS 1.9.2 on Linux.

Comment: well finally we've at least one interesting point in this mistery. I tested on ubuntu 12 and it's working, the url is loaded. Now I have some timeouts with the last step but I need more time to test it. Thanks!

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 12 with --ssl-protocol=tlsv1 and I still get about:blank

Comment: @DaltonTan You could try also adding `--ignore-ssl-errors=true`, but I'm not sure if that would help as I can't reproduce your issue.

Comment: Hey @hexid, thanks a lot for this answer. After breaking my head for the last 5 hours this has worked for me! I had tried `--ignore-ssl-errors=true` but that didn't help in my case.

Comment: None of these work for me. I am still getting the same warning.

Answer (score 7):

With my version of casperjs and phantomjs, the cli ssl protocol parameter was being ignored, I had to put it in a config file instead:

```
casperjs browse.js --config=<(echo '{"sslProtocol": "any"}') --ignore-ssl-errors=true
```